# How To get the full name of all processes running including kernel processes on windows

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to list all of the processes running in windows similar to how ProcessExplorer does, however i get lots of unknown processes using the code found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes)

[image]

I think these are kernel processes, but would there be any way to view their names?

Comment: That code is outdated. You can't get `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ` access to many processes if you don't have administrator access. Even with administrator access, you still may need SeDebugPrivilege enabled and may need to impersonate a SYSTEM access token to get such privileged access to protected system processes (e.g. `PsProtectedSignerWinTcb-Light` protection on smss.exe, wininit.exe, services.exe, and csrss.exe).

Comment: BTW, this isn't related to "kernel" processes -- i.e. those that have only kernel-mode threads (e.g. the System, System Idle, Registry). It's a function of the discretionary and mandatory access control on a process object, as well as its protection level.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing `<unknown>` in the process name is that they are system processes as you rightly predicted. `OpenProcess` which is trying to open with required permissions is failing and defaulting to unknown for system processes.

You can use [WTSEnumerateSessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumerateprocessesa) instead if you are looking for only process names and PIDs.

```
WTS_PROCESS_INFO* pWtsProcessInfo = NULL;
DWORD dwProcessCount = 0;
if (WTSEnumerateProcesses(NULL, NULL, 1, &pWtsProcessInfo, &dwProcessCount))    {
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwProcessCount; i++)      {
        printf("%ws : %d\n", pWtsProcessInfo[i].pProcessName, pWtsProcessInfo[i].ProcessId); // %s if the project is not in unicode
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you have the PID and are running as an administrator, enable SeDebugPrivilege, open with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access, and call  `QueryFullProcessImageName`.

Comment: identified WTSenumerableProcessA is undefined

Comment: From the MSDN documentation, you need to include    Header  wtsapi32.h
Library  Wtsapi32.lib